# How to store values to a temporary array from a input field and display it in an list in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I'm having a input field in my form.

- it is for getting the contact number
- User can add multiple contact numbers; so instead of using multiple fields for contact information I want to use a single input field
- Whenever user enters a number and (OnChange) event the contact should store in a temporary array and list in a list below.
- in that list if user wishes he can remove the contact he added if he wants

I have added my sample code. the requirement I need. I tried to do using my concept but I'm getting stuck.

**template.html**

```
   <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="md-form">
        <i class="fa fa-mobile prefix" style="font-size: 46px; margin-top: -10px;"></i>
        <input type="text" id="rec4" class="form-control" (change)="store()" ng-model="contact"> 
        <label for="rec4" class="">Contact Number</label>
        </div>
       </div>

<ul>
<li>{{data1}}></li><li><{{data2}}></li>
<ul>
```

**test.ts**

```
export class App {

public contact:any[];

}
  constructor( ) {


  }

}
```

My sample [Plunker code](https://plnkr.co/edit/XxfXB1GIspkpq2tEas3R?p=preview).

Comment: Hi Deepak. I've made a number of edits to your posts in the past in order to help current and future readers. Some of the same issues keep cropping up; I wonder if I could mention them to you, so volunteer editors have less work to do? Two things in particular: when referring to yourself ("I") it is always upper-case, with no exceptions. Also, there is no need to add "please help me" to your questions. Readers know you need help, so this rather seems like begging. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer :sure i will follow this procedures (Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your code with some changes

1. Set a local template variable on the input.
2. List with li and ngFor, don't forget to track with trackBy
3. Set the value to '' after enter
4. no model needed

**HTML**

```
 <input type="text" id="rec4" #input class="form-control" (change)="store(input.value); input.value=''"> 
....
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let d of data; let i=index; trackBy: trackByFn">
     {{d}}
  </li>
<ul>
```

**Typescript:**

```
store(newValue){
   this.data.push(newValue);
   console.log(this.data)
 }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qcnfty?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

I overcame that by using `keyup.enter`. Basically whenever you hit `ENTER` (return) key the function is invoked.

You can use it like following:

```
//template
<input type="text" (keyup.enter)="store()" [(ng-model)]="contact">
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let c of contactList">{{c}} <button (click)="removeContact(c)">remove</button> </li>
</ul>


//.ts
private contactList: Array<string> = [];
public store(){
    this.contactList.push(contact)
    this.contact = null;
}
public removeContact(number){
    //remove logic here...
}
```

This is just an example keeping in mind your context you can use it however you please.